# GetClipboardData(CF_HDROP) fails in cut and paste

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, clipboard

I have an MFC application to find the files in the clipboard, It's work fine when copying the file but fails during the cut and paste operation. When I live debugged it shows that GetClipboardData(CF_HDROP) fails and returns Error NO 1418.
here is my code

```
        TCHAR   lpszFileName[MAX_PATH];
        bool    bStart  = true; 
        CString csFile  ="",
                strErr  = "";
        bool    bOpen   = OpenClipboard(0);
        if(!bOpen)
        {
            strErr.Format("clipboard Error %d",GetLastError());
            WriteLog(TYPECAST_T0_LPTSTR strErr,1,1);
        }
        HGLOBAL hGlobal = (HGLOBAL)GetClipboardData(CF_HDROP);
        if (hGlobal)
        {
            HDROP hDrop = (HDROP)GlobalLock(hGlobal);
            if (hDrop)
            {   
                UINT fileCount = DragQueryFile(hDrop, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0, 0);
                UINT filenameLength;
                for (UINT i = 0; i < fileCount; ++i) 
                {
                    filenameLength = DragQueryFile(hDrop, i, 0, 0);
                    DragQueryFile(hDrop, i, lpszFileName, filenameLength+1);
                    csFile = (CString)lpszFileName;             
                    AddFileList(csFile);
                }
            }
        }

        else
        {
            strErr.Format("clipboard Error %d",GetLastError());
            WriteLog(TYPECAST_T0_LPTSTR strErr,1,1);
        }
        CloseClipboard();
        GlobalUnlock(hGlobal);
```

if anyone konws how to solve this, please share it

Comment: Paste event isn't captured. Monitoring the clipboard includes only Cut and Copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error 1418 is `ERROR_CLIPBOARD_NOT_OPEN`. I think it is because you forget don't close clipboard properly. `GlobalUnlock(hGlobal);` should reside inside of `if (hDrop)` block and gets called *before* closing clipboard. Also `OpenClipboard` returns `BOOL`, not `bool` and the returned `BOOL` value of `CloseClipboard` should be inspected.